# Building a .Net project from a Console Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, .net-6.0

I'm trying to set up a **CI/CD** enviroment, and decided to rely in **c#** as much as possible.

In order to do that, I created a console application that is going to be responsible from building several .Net projects.

One of those projects is a plain simple console application targeting .Net 6, but when building it, yields a couple of errors. The code from the builder project is this simple:

```
var projectFileName = @"..\..\..\..\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2.csproj";
var pc = new ProjectCollection();
var GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();

GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");
var BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), BuidlRequest);
```

I'm receiving the error:

> Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to
> the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found.  Manifest file path
> 'C:\Users\myUser\source\BuilderProject\bin\Debug\net6.0\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'.
> SDK resolver path:
> C:\Users\myUser\source\BuilderProject\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll
> C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\WpfApp1\ZConsoleApp2\ZConsoleApp2.csproj

Any clues in how to get rid of the error, on how to build a project from a .Net project? I have been flicking through many links but didn't find much information.

Thanks!

Comment: If you really want to rely on C# for your CI/CD process, I'd recommend looking at [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/)

Comment: Another useful framework could be https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

Comment: Another C# build automation system - [nuke](https://github.com/nuke-build/nuke).